# Strongswan ipsec site-site configuration

Tags: networking, encryption, tunnel, ipsec, strongswan

I'm configuring site-to-site ipsec tunnel using strongswan, but i don`t know how is ipsec tunnel opened on remote side (definitely without using strongswan)
When i try to connect - i get no response

```
initiating IKE_SA con[8] to 'remote-ip'
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]  

sending packet: from 'my-ip'[500] to 'remote'[500] (592 bytes)
retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 'my-ip'[500] to 'remote'[500] (592 bytes)
retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 'my-ip'[500] to 'remote'[500] (592 bytes)
retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 'my-ip'[500] to 'remote'[500] (592 bytes)
retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 'my-ip'[500] to 'remote'[500] (592 bytes)
retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
giving up after 5 retransmits
establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding
```

However, all details that i got:

```
AC USER VPN
Phase 1
IP Address           'remote-ip'
Pre-shared Key 
IKE Version          2


      P1 Proposal  
Encryption               AES256
Authentication           SHA256
Diffie-Hellman Groups    15
Key Life                 28800
Phase 2


       P2 Proposal  
Encryption               AES256
Authentication           SHA256
Diffie-Hellman Groups    15
Key Life                 3600
```

My ipsec.conf:

```
connection setup
conn %default
        ikelifetime=28800s
        keylife=3600s
        lifetime=3600s
        rekey=yes
        keyingtries=1
        authby=secret
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no
conn con
        left='my-ip'
        leftsubnet=%dynamic
        leftid=User
        leftfirewall=yes
        esp=aes256-sha256-modp3072!
        ike=aes256-sha256-modp3072!
        right='remote-ip'
        rightsubnet=%dynamic
        rightid=remote
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=add
```

my ipsec.secrets:

```
User remote : PSK this_is_my_psk
```

When i use ipsec statusall:

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.0, Linux 4.15.0-54-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 37 minutes, since Sep 04 15:19:18 2019
  malloc: sbrk 1466368, mmap 0, used 496880, free 969488
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 0
  loaded plugins: charon aes md4 des rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem fips-prf gmp curve25519 xcbc cmac hmac attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke vici updown xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  `my-ip`
  2a01:4f8:c2c:c164::1
Connections:
      con:  'my-ip'...'remote-ip'  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
      con:   local:  [User] uses pre-shared key authentication
      con:   remote: [remote] uses pre-shared key authentication
      con:   child:  dynamic === dynamic TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
```

UDP on port 500, protocols 50 and 51 is allowed
I cant figure out where is my mistake in configuration, and will appreciate any help

Update:

Comment: What message is retransmitted there? IKE_SA_INIT? IKE_AUTH? Posting the complete log usually helps a lot.

Comment: @ecdsa
Added full log information, thank you.
IKE_SA_INIT message is retransmitted, i think

Comment: This indicates a fundamental problem. Could be the wrong remote IP address, a firewall or routing problem or, if the responder actually receives the message, some other problem that causes it to reject the request. Or the response does not reach your host. You'd have to debug this further (e.g. using the remote host's log, via firewall packet counters, or with traffic captures).